# Could not bind socket : Permission denied

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, php, sockets

I would like to use port 443 in a PHP script, but seems like i don't have privilages to do so. 
That's the php error that occurs:

```
Could not bind socket : [13] Permission denied
```

that's the simple php code:

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/scripts/php/outputWhile.php");
$ip = "0.0.0.0";
$port = "443";

error_reporting(~E_WARNING);
if(!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0))){
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
    die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

// Bind the source address
if( !socket_bind($sock, $ip , $port) ){
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
    die("Could not bind socket : [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

while(true){
    $messageRecieved = "";
    $r = socket_recvfrom($sock, $messageRecieved, 512, 0, $remote_ip, $remote_port);
    echo $messageRecieved . "<br>";
}
```

?>

How can i give root privileges to that script?
I suppose i should add the user to the root group, but.. which user?

I'm using Amazon AWS VPS with Red Hat 7.2.1-2 distro, with Apache and LiteSpeed Web Server.

Thanks,
Davide.

Comment: A simple solution would be to add a NAT rule to redirect between port 443 and port 4430. Then your script can interact with port 4430 and have outbound and inbound datagrams renumbered. I've never tried that with UDP, but I can't think of any reason it wouldn't work.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz If i use NAT will the packet still be sent using the main protocol or would it change something? I need to exchange packet from a php client to a php server using QUIC protocol.

Comment: Port NAT just allows the application to use port 4430 to send and receive datagrams that are actually sent from and to port 443. It has no effect on the protocol layered on top of UDP.